# Aligning image to center and button to bottom of the screen but image and button comes next to each other

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

What changes should I make to align button at bottom. `Buttons` class to display `button` widget is defined in another file.

```
class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Color(0xFFFFCCCC),
        body: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Image.asset(
              'assets/images/TransperentBackgroundBlack.png',
              height: 250,
            ),
            
            Align(
              alignment:Alignment.bottomCenter,
            child:Buttons(),
            ),
            
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to center a widget (image) in the middle of the screen, and add another widget (button) at the bottom **without descentre the first widget**, you can wrap all in a `Stack()` widget and use the `Center()` widget for the image and `Positioned()` widget for the button.

Like this:

```dart
class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        children: [
          Center(
            child: Container( // Your Image
              height: 100,
              width: 100,
              child: Placeholder(),
            ),
          ),
          Positioned(
            bottom: 0,
            child: Container( // Your Button
              height: 30,
              width: 100,
              child: Placeholder(),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[Result on device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FHfXp.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can but the buttons in the bottomAppBar and make the elevation to be 0.0 and make the image be in a center widget

```
class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Color(0xFFFFCCCC),
        body: Center(
          child:
            Image.asset(
              'assets/images/TransperentBackgroundBlack.png',
              height: 250,
            ),
        ),
      bottomNavigatorBar:BottomAppBar(
      child: Buttons(),         
        )
      ),
    );
  }
}
```